# How do I access the newly created attribute from triggered send?

Tags: marketing-cloud, api, soap-api, soap

If I create a subscriber like the one below, and use it in a triggered send, how do I access the new attribute?

```
        Subscriber subscriber = new Subscriber();
        subscriber.Attributes = new ExactTargetAPI.Attribute[1];
        subscriber.Attributes[0] = new ExactTargetAPI.Attribute();
        subscriber.Attributes[0].Name = "NewAttributeName";
        subscriber.Attributes[0].Value = "NewAttributeValue";
```

Comment: How do you wish to access it?  API?  Within the application?

Comment: We want to access the new attribute within the email template. I.E. <getNewAttributeName>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To access the newly created data within our email template we had to create the new field in the Subscriber Profile Management center. This solved the problem we were running into.

Answer (score 2):

From inside an email template within the application, you would just use the personalization syntax, %%NewAttributeName%% where NewAttributeName is the actual name you gave it in your code sample.  Hope this helps!

Comment: If the API is creating the new attribute externally, would the same process apply?

Comment: By this I mean, if the data is being transferred into ET via the API, would we still access the data using the same manner?